# SVG loaded as data URI doesn't render <image> tags

Tags: javascript, html, svg

For a basic

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="60" height="60">
    <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="30" />
    <image x="0" y="0" width="60" height="60" xlink:href="//cloudfront.net/mysite/pages/1234/attachments/original/1234567890/MyIcon.svg?123456789" />
</svg>
```

When I inline that, or load as an external resource, it will render both the circle and the image as expected. However, I take the exact same SVG, and render it into an `<img>` using a data URI, the circle will load but not the svg `<image>`:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');

// Grab our SVG element
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
// Load its contents as a data URI
img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;uft8,' + svg.outerHTML;

// Put this image on the bottom
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

It's odd since it must be the exact same content. I was thinking it might be a CORS issue, but I don't see any errors or warnings in my console.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jkoudys/x4uhch7a/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When SVG is used as an image (in this case via an `<img>` tag) it must be complete in a single file to protect user privacy. This is [documented here](http://www.w3.org/TR/svg-integration/#secure-animated-mode)

Otherwise an SVG image hosted on a site could send out messages to another site indicating that it had been viewed while a raster image could not. Your mental model of what an image could do should not depend on whether it's an SVG image or a raster image.

So you need to convert the embedded image itself to a data URI before you convert the SVG file to a data URI.

Comment: This appears to be the case. Strange that there's no option for CORS around this - I was expecting a similar approach to how canvas has the 'tainted' state, or at very least for it to throw out an error. I can't seem to find any documentation of this anywhere - any thoughts on where you'd expect this to be covered?

Comment: The presence of open redirectors make it unsuitable as something CORS could work around. I've added a documentation link to the answer.